# lua: write result of io.popen to a file?

Tags: lua

I would like to take the result of `f = io.popen(command)` to a file.  Is there a way to do it from the file-descriptor `f`, or do I have to copy the data to a new string and write that via a new file-descriptor?

Answer (score 3):

this is about as simple as it's going to get without knowing more about what you're trying to do...

```
local fout = io.open("/path/to/file", "w+")
f = io.popen(command)
fout:write(f:read("*a"))
```

Comment: Hm, I can't get this to work. The file I specify in io.open() doesn't change. I'm getting info (my Gmail inbox) via a `curl` command; the lua script returns the count of unread messages, and I want to store the XML data string for external processing.

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? do you get an error at runtime? does it not print what you'd expect, etc? put the smallest working example of your code in the original question and i'll try to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

No standard way to do that in plain Lua. But you always may redirect the output to file in the `command` itself. (I.e. `io.popen("echo foo | tee bar")`, or `os.execute("echo foo >bar")`.)